# how to apply 2 css styles in 1 div class?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to move a shortcode which I put in Wordpress header. The problem is that from the 2 css rules below only the first works. If I change the order then again only the first works.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .right-header-wrap-flags {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 22px;
        }

.navigation-wrap{ 
padding-top: 60px;

} @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
.right-header-wrap-flags {
position: relative;
left: 600px; 
top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a bracket at the end

Comment: It's a little bit generic question.... First you miss a close bracket.

Comment: the media screen that is on top works and the second doesn't. same if change the order only the top media screen works

Comment: If your page is fo example 900px, it works the first condition... I thin you have to learn more about media queries

Comment: i know that but the problem is that only the first media rule applies even if i switch the order again the media rule that is on top works only

Comment: Have you correct the missing bracket?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the "Navigation-wrap" class to be part of the first media query:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .right-header-wrap-flags {
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            left: 22px;
            }
    
      .navigation-wrap{ 
      padding-top: 60px;
    
     }
    } <-- this was missing!
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .right-header-wrap-flags {
    position: relative;
    left: 600px; 
    top: 50px;
    }
}
```

if "navigation-wrap" should be independent from your media querys:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .right-header-wrap-flags {
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            left: 22px;
            }
    } <-- this was missing!
      .navigation-wrap{ 
      padding-top: 60px;
    
     }
    
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .right-header-wrap-flags {
    position: relative;
    left: 600px; 
    top: 50px;
    }
  }
```

reason: You forgot the bracket, which basically meant that the second media query was aprt of your first, so it could never occur! When your screen size reached 1025px the first media query is not active anymore and the second one was inside of the first one, so it also couldnt happen anymore. That should fix it

Comment: thank you for your reply. changed it but still the same

Comment: check with the browser inspector what media query is used

Comment: So if you change the screen size to over 1025px the first rule still applies?

Comment: there is still one more bracket missing at the very end. Double check.

Comment: @Pantelis Sarras how are you changing the screen size to check your code? I tried it out in an example and it works fine for me

Comment: on dekstop is uses the min width 1025 query but it has warning triangles and says unknow property name and invalid property name

Comment: Okay, cause to check if it works you can basically just put the browser you are displaying your code with in windowed mode and drag it wider and thinner to just see if it applies. I used the code i put in my answer with a simple <div> containint just a word and if i drag the browser window around it jumps positions..which means both media queries work fine. You can also just open the development console, for example on chrome with F12, then select the content your css should apply to and watch in the Console how it changes

Comment: this is how i am testing this too. the min query works fine which means that when the menu breaking for mobile it moves where it should be the desktop doesn't work and i sse warnings for unknow property name in css lines

Comment: @PantelisSarras Oh thats a whole different story. That could mean that you have some exotic characters that need special encoding in your css file. The Console warning you get should also include the property names that are affected by the error

Comment: managed to fix it without even knowing how. just rewrote the code. thank you everyone for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318932/css-error-in-browser-unknown-property-name-when-using-pseudo-after

check this out to avoid that in the future. I bet that some weird characters slipped into the code by accident. You probably copy pasted the code and that fixed it even tho it looks the same? or deleted and rewrote it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes , Only the first CSS code works, you should use javascript, to change the styles based on the Conditions you specify .